# Is there anything wrong with html {font-size: 1px;} for working with REM units?

Tags: css, fonts

`html {font-size: 62.5%;}` seems like the standard approach to set the base font-size to 10px.

E.g.,

```
html {font-size: 62.5%;}  /* 10px */
body {font-size: 1.5rem;} /* 15px */
```

But this creates a dependency on the browser's font-size 16px. This seems unreliable in the long run... why not just...

```
html {font-size: 1px;}  /* 1px */
body {font-size: 15rem;} /* 15px */
```

Is there a technical problem with this? It seems cleaner and much more reliable. Why don't I see people do this?

Comment: Might be a problem for any browser that doesn't support rems.

Comment: Pixel fallback `body {font-size: 15px; font-size: 15rem;}` Is there other reasons?

Comment: I'd say the main issue is any SE reading your 1px font will consider your whole site as spam. Also, I really don't see much more than a MARGINAL benefit at best, with possibly A LOT of problems. This being said, from a technical POV, I don't think you'll have an issue as long as you don't care about almighty Google. btw, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519545/font-size-1px-to-use-with-rem-units

Comment: So maybe `html {font-size: 10px;}` then. Using fixed units seems more reliable than percentages that rely on the browser `html {font-size: 62.5%;}` Why do people do that?

Comment: @Blastercloud - Once upon a time, there was a very popular browser that wouldn't let a user zoom the text size to suit if the fonts were set in absolute pixels, whereas if the fonts were defined as percentages of the original font size, it would. So it was user friendlier to start with a font size of 62.5%.

Comment: I see... so today `html {font-size: 10px;}` should be better, no?

Comment: The setting `font-size: 62.5%` sets the font size to 62.5% of the inherited size, which can be literally anything, even for the `html` element. If you want to set font size to 15px no matter what, it is surely best to set it to `15px` directly. So what is the question? Surely your approach is very risky; consider what happens when the user style sheet has `html { font-size: 18pt !important }`.

Comment: i've encountered some weird bug with this approach

Comment: @user151496 Can you please elaborate on what the bug was?

Comment: @Arad you do realize I posted this a year and half ago right? Don't know, but I think it had something to do with incorrect rendering in some browsers on OS that had native resolution scaling turned on

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time, there was IE and text scaling only. Other browsers came and abandoned the concept in favor of scaling the whole viewport. After all, if you're having a hard time reading the text, you probably have a hard time seeing images and other non-text elements too.

When you're working with relative font-sizes, at some point they have to be converted to the base pixels on the screen. The default modifier is by and large expected to be 16px, you can imagine it as a declaration on an element 1 level above `<html>`. Any base modifications, like `62.5%` on the body for 1 relative unit to equal 10px, scale off that value.

With that in mind, what you're effectively doing is taking matters into your own hands, overwriting the browser base font-size above `<html>` and setting it to 1px value instead, resulting in 1 em/rem being always equal to 1px inside the body. However, there is a price - the browser is no more able to propagate it's own base font value because of your direct pixel value, so any font-size settings the user may have set are neglected by your declaration. In other words, using the 1px trick disables the pure font-size zoom of the browser. At the same time however, font-size only scaling remains fundamentally flawed in it's intention (look at google.com results with scaled font).

If you'd like to retain the ability of the browser to control the font-size only zoom AND at the same time work with 1rem = 1px, you probably want this instead. edit: I should note that this will be problematic in Chrome due to the minimum font size settings (6px default). Paddings and margins will scale off this value as minimum.

```css
html {
  font-size: 6.25%;
}
body {
  font-size: 16rem;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a very easy case for browsers to handle, just scale the root em value whether explicit or not.

Comment: Very easy if you are someone who can rewrite browser features without asking anyone's permission and somehow erase all previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

In **2020**, you can do this in Chrome by going to:

`chrome://settings/fonts`

then slide the minimum font size from 6px to 0.
Now, Chrome won't override the minimum of any font size.